# Elementary Bernoulli-Type Inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

> What is an alternate way to demonstrate the inequality
>   $$1+\frac{x}{n+1}\leq\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^x$$
>   where $n$ is a natural number more than $0$ and $x$ is strictly between $0$ and $1$?

Seeing how Bernoulli's Inequality implies
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^x\leq 1+\frac{x}{n}\,,$$
this is a fairly tight inequality.

I was able to prove this inequality with elementary calculus by considering the function
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^x-\frac{x}{n+1}-1$$
on $(0,1)$ and appealing to the fairly tight inequality
$$\frac{1}{n}\geq \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\geq\frac{1}{n+1}\,.$$
I was hoping somebody could derive this inequality more directly however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^x
&=\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{-x}\tag1\\
&\ge\left(1-\frac{x}{n+1}\right)^{-1}\tag2\\[3pt]
&\ge1+\frac{x}{n+1}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: reciprocal of reciprocal
$(2)$: reciprocal of the Bernoulli inequality for $0\le x\le1$
$(3)$: $1\ge1-x^2$

Answer (score 2):

Since you know that $$
\frac{1}{n+1}\leq \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) \tag{1}
$$
you can rewrite
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^x = e^{x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)} 
\operatorname*{\geq}_{(1)} e^{\frac{x}{n+1}} \geq 1+\frac{x}{n+1}
$$
the last inequality being the standard $1+u \leq e^u$.

Note that this implies the inequality holds for all $x\in(0,\infty)$, not only in $(0,1)$.